# post multipart image to api

Tags: python, python-2.7

Posting with postman:

Request Payload:

```
------WebKitFormBoundaryiPTu5XrX314NHpan
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="photo"; filename="example1.jpg"
Content-Type: image/jpeg


------WebKitFormBoundaryiPTu5XrX314NHpan--
```

In headers:

```
Content-Type:multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundaryiPTu5XrX314NHpan
```

Need to send images from python app, but getting 400 error everytime.

Tries:

```
req = urllib2.Request(photoURL, None, {'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5'})
imgFile = cStringIO.StringIO(urllib2.urlopen(req).read())
datagen, headers = multipart_encode({"photo": Image.open(imgFile)})
request = urllib2.Request(postPhotoAPI, datagen, headers)
request.add_header("Authorization", authKey)
urllib2.urlopen(request).read()
```

Result: 400

Same in requests.post and some other post functions (also for base64).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I always use python [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) library when i want to make http calls with python.

You need to do something like this:

```
files = {'photo': ('image.png', open('image.png', 'rb'), 'image/png')}
r = requests.post(photoURL, header={'User-agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; de; rv:1.9.1.5) Gecko/20091102 Firefox/3.5.5', 'Authorization': authKey} files=files)
print r.text
```

You can read more [here](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file).

Comment: Thanks, it helped me a lot. I didn't know that there is option files in requests.